# Showing a specific property of an object from a list in a Listbox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, list, listbox

I'm creating a form in which the user inserts the name, brand and price of a product. These three are saved as properties of an object in a list of object, like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Product prod = new Product();
   string kind = textBox1.Text;
   prod.Kind = kind;
   string brand = textBox2.Text;
   prod.Brand = brand;
   double price = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
   prod.Price = price;

   listofthings.Add(prod);
}
```

What I want to do now is add a listbox in which the property 'kind' of each object is displayed, so the user can select specific products to buy.

i have tried

```
listBox2.DataSource = listofthings.prod.Kind;
```

but it won't allow it. 
A little help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bind listbox to your object, and set property [`DisplayMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx) to name of bound object's property that you want to display in listbox:

```
listBox2.DataSource = listofthings;
listBox2.DisplayMember = "Kind";
```

Comment: I thought that this kind of function was only available in WPF :) I've been using WPF for too long.